# How can I delete my old LinkedIn account if I no longer have the associated email address/phone number?

Tags: linkedin

I created a LinkedIn account 6 years ago that I no longer use but still shows up in Google search results.

I am uncertain whether I used an email address or phone number when the account was originally set up, however, I no longer have access to either.

I use a different LinkedIn account and don't want search results returning outdated information and/or directing people to the old account.

How can I remove the old account without the associated email address or phone number?

Answer (score 1):

From LinkedIn Help - [No Access to Email Address](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1501/no-access-to-email-address?lang=en):

> There are instances when you no longer use or have access to the email address used to register your LinkedIn account. We suggest first trying to sign in with a **secondary email address** or **phone number** that's associated with your account. We allow you to sign in with any email address or phone number associated with your account.
>
> If you haven't been able to recover your password or don't have access to an email address associated with your account, we can help by verifying your identity. This ensures that there is no unauthorized access to your account. [Learn More](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/127580) about how we verify identity and how we keep your information safe.
>
> Please follow the steps below on desktop:
>
> 1. In the Sign-in screen, click on **Forgot Password**.
> 2. Enter the email ID associated with your account and click on **Find Account**.
> 3. In the following screen you will be asked to enter a verification code sent to your email.
> 4. Since you don’t have access to this email ID, click on the **Verify your identity**.
> 5. Once you begin the identity verification process, you'll be asked to take a photo of your ID with your smartphone or webcam.
> 6. Enter the new email address you want associated with your account and your [profile URL](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/49315).
> 7. On the following page, upload a picture of a valid ID card or passport. Next, we'll ask you to provide an image of a valid passport or government ID. After you submit, we'll process your information and be in contact to assist you further.
>
> We ask for your ID card to ensure that only you regain access to your account and no unauthorized entity is given access.
>
> Follow [this link to verify your identity](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/request-password-reset).
>
> **Note:** If you only have one email address and it has bounced, you'll not be able to send a confirmation link to yourself. You will have to [verify your identity to regain access to your account](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/request-password-reset).